# Como contar o número de caracteres da palavra que veio da primeira linha de um arquivo de texto?

Tags: php, arquivo, fopen

Abaixo temos um exemplo de como contar o número de caracteres de uma string:

```
$palavra ="coisa";
echo strlen($palavra); //retorna o número 5
```

No entanto estou pegando esta palavra de um arquivo de texto e a **strlen** não está funcionando, veja:

```
$f = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");
echo fgets($f); // Até aqui funciona: ecoa "casa".
echo strlen($f); //A primeira palavra do arquivo de texto é "casa", 
                //  mas o echo não ecoa 4.
```

Ja tentei fazer desta forma também e não deu certo:

```
$f = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");
$palavra = fgets($f); 
echo strlen($palavra); // Está ecoando 6 que não corresponde aos 4 caracteres da       
                      //palavra "casa".
```

**OBS.:** atualmente o arquivo contém **3 palavras**, cada uma em uma linha. Mas pretendo colocar mais palavras.

Passei a fazer da forma abaixo, mas ainda assim não está retornando 4 caracteres para casa, está retornando sempre 3 caracteres a mais d apalavra que coloco na primeira linha no arquivo:

```
 $f = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");
 $palavra = fgets($f);
 echo strlen(trim($palavra));
```

**ACRESCENTADO EM 25/08/2014**

Galera, como cada palavra é um array de caracteres eu fui tentar imprimir na tela para checar se imprimiria algo a mais que as quatro letras da palavra "casa", descobri que a palavra casa está em:

```
echo $palavra[3];
echo $palavra[4];
echo $palavra[5];
echo $palavra[6];
```

**O que está no 0, 1 e 2? Eu fiz um for para imprimir tudo e as três primeiras posições
aparecem na tela como losangos com um sinal de interrogação**

Eu setei tanto o meta do html quanto o arquivo na hora de salvar para para utf-8 .

Já tentei utf8_decode e nada.

Eu imaginei que se eu tirasse sempre 3 caracteres do resultado resolveria meu problema fui pesquisar e encontrei esta pergunta do satckoverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057742/how-to-remove-efbbbf-in-php-string

Um cara faz exatamente isso, mas outro também adverte que descartar o BOM não é uma boa ideia,até porque se uma hora o BOM não for setado eu estaria deixando de contar 3 caracteres de minha palavra. Eu não quero fazer gambiarra. Quero entender.

Olha meu código final funcionando:

```
//Nesse arquivo na primeira linha tenho somente a palavra "casa"
$f = fopen("palavras.txt","r");
$palavra = fgets($f);
$car= strlen(trim($palavra)) - 3;
echo $car;
//Com o código acima retorno o valor 4, sem o (-3) retorna 7.
```

**Ma será adequdo?**

**RESOLVIDO! SALVANDO SEM O BENDITO "BOM"! NO NOTEPAD++ TEM QUE IR EM

> ENCODING

PORQUE NO NOTEPAD DO WINDOWS NÃO TEM ESSA OPÇÃO.**

Obrigado a todos! A resposta do @Jader é muito útil e com certeza vou utilizar, mas de acordo com a pergunta caso alguém mais do fórum precise dessa informação o @bfavaretto colocou tudo.

Comment: O arquivo contém uma só palavra? Sempre? Podem ser duas palavras? Várias linhas? . . . O melhor é [edit] a pergunta para esclarecer isso.

Comment: Detalhes adicionados.

Comment: Na verdade, estou tentando entender sua pergunta e a resposta do bfavaretto no contexto do seu comentário *"E como medir somente a palavra?*"... se tem só uma palavra por linha e o código dele lê a primeira linha, não entendo qual é o problema...

Comment: Eu sei que logicamente falando possa ter soado estranho para você, mas é que mesmo usando o "trim", continua retornando 3 caracteres a mais do que o que a palavra realmente tem.

Comment: Isso só acontece com a primeira linha? As outras linhas a contagem bate? Pode ser que seja o BOM do UTF-8 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Olha, vou usar a resposta do @Jader para checar as outras linhas, mas se tratando dessa forma simples eu nem sei como buscar a segunda linha.

Comment: O @bfavaretto mencionou isso, mas como removo BOM caso esteja sendo empregado? Eu setei tanto o meta do html quanto o arquivo na hora de salvar para para utf-8 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variável `$f` representa o arquivo. O comando `fgets($f)` lê a próxima linha do arquivo (no seu exemplo, a primeira). Portanto não faz sentido tentar medir `$f`, você precisa medir `fgets($f)`:

```
$f = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");
$linha = fgets($f);
echo strlen($linha);
```

Como apontado pelo @mgibsonbr, o retorno do [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgets.php) inclui a quebra de linha. Num arquivo contendo somente a palavra "casa" e formatado em Windows, isso quer dizer `casa\r\n`, ou seja, o retorno de carro e a quebra de linha contam e o comprimento dá `6`. Você pode usar [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) para remover esses caracteres (ele remove espaços em branco no começo e no fim da string, incluindo quebras de linha e tabs):

```
echo strlen(trim($linha));
```

Outro detalhe importante: na codificação UTF-8, certos caracteres, como os acentuados, irão ocupar mais de um byte, e o PHP vai medir incorretamente o comprimento nesses casos. Para resolver, você precisará usar a função [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php):

```
echo mb_strlen(trim($linha));
```

Para ler todas as linhas, basta usar um loop. Juntando tudo, fica assim:

```
$f = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");
while($linha = fgets($f) !== false) {
    echo $linha . ' - ' . mb_strlen(trim($linha)) . '<br>';
}
```

---

Sobre o PHP estar retornando 3 caracteres a mais na contagem da primeira linha, tudo indica que seu arquivo TXT está com a codificação UTF-8 com BOM (*byte order mask*). Você precisa alterar a codificação para UTF-8 sem BOM. A maneira de fazer isso depende do editor, geralmente fica no próprio diálogo de salvar, ou numa opção separada de *encoding*.

Comment: Mesmo com o trim está retornando sempre 3 caracteres a mais da palavra que coloco na primeira linha no arquivo.

Comment: Talvez você tenha salvo o arquivo como UTF-8 "com BOM". Isso pode causar caracteres extras no início. @IWannaKnow

Comment: Não setei como BOM. Ao menos não intencionalmente. Nem tem essa opção na hora de salvar o txt. Acrescentei detalhes no final da pergunta.

Comment: Pela sua descrição, está sim com BOM, @IWannaKnow. O comprimento do BOM é 3 bytes, que é a diferença que você está vendo. Procure no seu editor uma opção que diga explicitamente UTF8 sem BOM.

Comment: Pois é, não tem essa opção. Veja o que tem: http://goo.gl/2p58pS

Comment: Que editor você está usando? Complementei minha resposta, mas realmente você vai precisar resolver esse problema de encoding.

Comment: Tente usar outro editor, como o Notepad++ @IWannaKnow

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, já vinha avisar, Obrigado pela ajuda! Mas nem configura na hora de salvar, tem que ir em settings - preferences - new document. Valeu cara!

Comment: No Notepad ++ é só ir em ENCODING.

Answer (score 5):

Para conseguir percorrer todas as palavras você precisa fazer algo assim:

```
$texto = file_get_contents('teste.txt');

$palavras = preg_split('/[\s\r\n\t[:punct:]]+/', $texto, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$tamanhos = array();
foreach($palavras as $palavra) $tamanhos[] = strlen($palavra);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($palavras); $i++) {
    echo  $i . '.) "' . $palavras[$i] . '"  - ' . $tamanhos[$i] . '<br>';
}
```

**teste.txt**

```
Casa grande é outra coisa!
Mas, custa caro para manter...
```

**Resultado:**

```
0.) "Casa" - 4
1.) "grande" - 6
2.) "é" - 1
3.) "outra" - 5
4.) "coisa" - 5
5.) "Mas" - 3
6.) "custa" - 5
7.) "caro" - 4
8.) "para" - 4
9.) "manter" - 6
```

Para pegar uma palavra aleatoriamente use o `rand()` assim:

```
$r = rand(0,sizeof($palavras)-1);

echo 'Palavra aleatoria: ' . $palavras[$r] . ' - ' . $tamanhos[$r];

// Resultado:
// Palavra aleatoria: coisa - 5
```

Comment: Gostei Jader, obrigado. Diz uma coisa se depois eu quiser selecionar uma palavra que está nesse array aleatoriamente?

Comment: @IWannaKnow editei a resposta e inclui uma forma de pegar uma palavra aleatoriamente...

Comment: Muito bom! Valeu!